# SVN External Files / Folders

Tags: svn, svn-externals

Could someone share some info or reference links which sheds some in-depth information on how SVN handles 'external' folders / files. I did get some links from SO and some other sites, but none of them explain it in detail. I am developing a generic API that need to support most of the available CM tools (SVN, PTC Integrity, TFS etc).

Regards, 
Joe.

Comment: Are you sure that you ask about externals definitions `svn:externals` which are in-depth described in the SVNBook? http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.externals.html

Comment: As far as I know there's no such thing as "shared file or folder" in SVN, so to me this question makes no sense.

Comment: @Dialecticus I guess he's asking about externals definitions, but in such case these 3 questions are "invalid".

Comment: Or it is just that in SVN every file and folder in the repository can be considered "shared" as it is called by Joe.

Comment: @Robert reading manual is still the best way to get proper answer to the question, IMHO.

Comment: @Dialecticus : Sorry, I forgot to mention that. Yes, I'm referring to svn:externals. <br/> By sharing what I intended to mean was a scenario where in you have common files (say libraries) stored in a single folder and referenced in various projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ask about how `svn:externals` versioned property operates, then the best resource to learn about this feature is [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/), see [SVNBook | Externals Definitions](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.externals.html). The book covers this topic very well, in fact.

For SharpSVN's documentation see http://docs.sharpsvn.net/current/.

Comment: Thanks. I will refer that book in depth.

Comment: The SVN book does not cover the topic in a concise and accessible way IMO. Best resource would be a sharp SO answer.

Answer (score 1):

As Dialecticus already commented, there is no such thing as a 'shared folder' or a 'shared file' in Subversion.

You can bring something else in your working copy using `svn:externals` but that doesn't really make it shared.

If you are wrapping your own api around it, you could just as well use multiple working copies in a single tree... As that is really all what an external adds you: making it easy to checkout and update from multiple locations.

Answer (score 1):

Must read the documentation. `svn:externals` is just a property of the folder, and other property for instance is `svn:ignore`. These two have special meaning for SVN, but there are other as well (with prefix different from `svn:`)

Downside to a SVN external is that if it belongs to a different repository then it is not possible to commit changes in both root working copy and external's WC in a single action. If external actually belongs to the same repository as the root WC then TortoiseSVN does some magic to actually make it possible to commit them in single action.

`svn:externals` property can pin the revision of the working copy, but this feature is usually only used for [tagging](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.tags.html) folders.